# Is there a way to add JQuery zoom to a product picture in a new theme in shopify?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shopify, liquid

The article I will reference can be found here: https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/jquery-image-zoom

I have followed the steps of the JQuery zoom to a tee and I still cannot get the plug-in to work.

1. JQuery is installed in the project
2. I added the plugin file to the assets folder
3. I edited the 'product-template.liquid' file to add the data-zoom attribute and to add the class 'image-zoom' to the image tag
4. I added the script from the site to the 'product-template.liquid' file, but I'm not sure if that's where it is supposed to be.

Theoretically, the zoom should be working right? I've tried a bunch of different fiddling with the code and nothing seems to be working.

I am new to editing shopify code as well as JS so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can see the images perfectly the only thing that's missing is the zoom.

My code for images in 'product-template.liquid':

```
{%- for image in product.images -%}
        <div class="image-container product-single__photo product__photo-container product__photo-container-{{ section.id }} js{% unless image == featured_image %} hide{% endunless %}"
             id="ProductPhoto"
             style="max-width: {% include 'image-width' with image: image, width: 480 %}px;"
             data-image-id="{{ image.id }}">
          <a href="{{ image | img_url: '2048x2048' }}" 
             class="js-modal-open-product-modal product__photo-wrapper product__photo-wrapper-{{ section.id }}"
             style="padding-top:{{ 1 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | times: 100}}%;">
            {% assign img_url = image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' %}
            <img class="lazyload{% unless image == featured_image %} lazypreload{% endunless %} image-zoom"
              src="{{ image | img_url: '150x150' }}"
              data-src="{{ img_url }}" 
              data-widths="[180, 240, 360, 480, 720, 960, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048]"
              data-aspectratio="{{ image.aspect_ratio }}"
              data-sizes="auto"
              alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}"
              data-zoom="{{ image | img_url: '2048x2048', scale: 2 }}">
          </a>
          
        </div> 
      {%- endfor -%}
```

When previewing the product page I get
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7AXc.png) error three times.

Tiger queen is the product variant, I think it's showing error because it's just a preview of the website but I'm not sure.

Comment: I believe the img_url needs to be an actual url of the file that contains the larger image, the jquery error is telling you that such a file doesn't exists and the address in the error looks broken

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `img_url` needs to be an actual url of the file that contains the larger image, the jquery error is telling you that such a file doesn't exists and the address in the error looks broken

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, because the img_url is meant to be arbitrary as this function is made for every product-page on the site. If I do need to change it, what should I change it to without making it a specific url?

Comment: you would need a larger version of the image right, you need to store that file somewhere and supply it to the js function, I think that's the role of img_url - to be a specific url of the larger version of the image. Try hardcoding it to see if that works

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to supply the '%7Bwidth%7Dx.png' or why it is even being accessed. I looked '%7Bwidth%7Dx.png' up and there are other people who seem to have to same problem as me with the exact same url linking to nothing.

Comment: In order to get the plugin to zoom, you need an actual larger image file. That's something you need to supply yourself, and upload it to the server. Then instead of '%7Bwidth%7Dx.png' you'll have 'your_actual_large_image_file_address.png' passed as `img-url`. The reason is that you need to supply the JS plugin with the larger image file, it can't just zoom in on your small image (for performance reasons you are not loading the full size image for the small version as well)